# Could you please help me with web scraping using Rvest?

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am currently trying to webscrape the following website: https://chicago.suntimes.com/crime/archives

I have been relying on the CSS Selector Gadget to find the x-path and to do web scraping. However, I am unable to use the gadget in this website and I would have to use the Inspect Source to find what I need. I have been trying to find the relevant css and xpath by scrolling down each source, but I was not able to do it due to my limited capabilities.

Could you please help me find the xpath or css for

- Title
- Author
- Date

I am so sorry if this is a dry laundry list of everything... but I am really stuck. I will really appreciate if you could give me some help!

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you cant find something easy with the CSS Selector Gadget , I highly recommend diving into the developer tools. I spend the better half of day to find a specific XPATH in the develop tools. Once you get the hang of it, you can really improve your scraping and you are independent of the Selector Gadget. Additionally, youll get a much better understanding about how the website you are scraping is build! Have fun scraping ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element that you want to extract if you find the relevant tag with it's respective class using selector gadget you'll be able to get what you want.

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://chicago.suntimes.com/crime/archives'

webpage <- url %>% read_html() 
title <- webpage %>% html_nodes('h2.c-entry-box--compact__title') %>% html_text()
author <- webpage %>% html_nodes('span.c-byline__author-name') %>% html_text()
date <- webpage %>% html_nodes('time.c-byline__item')%>% html_text() %>% trimws()
result <- data.frame(title, author, date)
result

result
#                                                                                               title              author        date
#1                               Belmont Cragin man charged with carjacking in Little Village: police       Sun-Times Wire February 17
#2                                                   Gas station robbed, man carjacked in Horner Park       Jermaine Nolen February 17
#3                                                              8 shot, 2 fatally, Tuesday in Chicago       Sun-Times Wire February 17
#4                                        Businesses robbed at gunpoint on the Northwest Side: police       Sun-Times Wire February 17
#5                                                              Man charged with carjacking in Aurora       Sun-Times Wire February 16
#6                                                       Woman fatally stabbed in Park Manor apartment      Sun-Times Wire February 16
#7                                                        Woman critically hurt by gunfire in Woodlawn       David Struett February 16
#8                                Teen boy, 17, charged with attempted carjacking in Back of the Yards      Sun-Times Wire February 16
#...
#...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful....! Thank you!!!!!